# Combining elements of a list if condition is met

Tags: python

I have some python code, with its final output being a list:

```
['JAVS P 0 060107084657.30', '59.41 0 S', ' CEY P 0 060107084659.39', '03.10 0 S', 'CADS P 0 060107084703.67', 'VISS P 0 060107084704.14']
```

Now, I would like to join the lines, that do not start with sta (JAVS, CEY, CADS, VISS,...) with the previous one.
I get this element of the list with:

```
if not element.startswith(sta):
  print element
```

How to proceed with joining the elements?

Final output should be like this:

```
[u'JAVS P 0 060107084657.30       59.41 0 S']
[u' CEY P 0 060107084659.39       03.10 0 S']
[u'CADS P 0 060107084703.67']
[u'VISS P 0 060107084704.14']
```

Full code:

```
import glob
from obspy import read_events
import itertools

####### Definitions

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

####### Script

#write_file = open("hypoell", "w")

path = 'events/'
event_files = glob.glob(path + '*.hyp')

fmt_p = '%s %s %s %s'
fmt_s = '%s %s %s'


for event_file in event_files:

  cat = read_events(event_file)
  event = cat[0]

  lines = []

  for pick in event.picks:
    sta = pick.waveform_id.station_code
    if len(sta) <= 3:
        sta = " "+sta
    else:
        sta=sta
    phase = pick.phase_hint

    year = pick.time.year
    month = pick.time.month
    day = pick.time.day
    hh = pick.time.hour
    minute = pick.time.minute
    sec = pick.time.second
    ms = pick.time.microsecond


    p_time = pick.time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f")
    p_time = p_time[2:-4]

    s_time = pick.time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f")
    s_time = s_time[12:-4]

    if phase == "P":
        p_line = fmt_p %(sta, phase, 0, p_time)
        lines.append(str(p_line))
    if phase == "S":
        s_line = fmt_s %(s_time, 0, "S")
        lines.append(str(s_line))

########################################################################
print lines

prefixes = ('JAVS', ' CEY', 'CADS', 'VISS')

for a, b in pairwise(lines):
    if a[0].startswith(prefixes):
        if not b[0].startswith(prefixes):
            print a + b
        else:
            print a
```

Comment: Do you have a list of lists?

Comment: I guess. I tried printing type(lines) - lines is the name of the list that I am appending in the code to, and the output is:

`code`<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>`code`

Comment: Sorry, mistake, it is not list of lists. I had list defined two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple loop assuming `mydata` is non-empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

mydata = [
    [u'JAVS P 0 060107084657.30'],
    ['59.41 0 S'],
    [u' CEY P 0 060107084659.39'],
    ['03.10 0 S'],
    [u'CADS P 0 060107084703.67'],
    [u'VISS P 0 060107084704.14'],
]

prefixes = (u'JAVS', u' CEY', u'CADS', u'VISS')

a = [u'']
for b in mydata:
    if a[0].startswith(prefixes):
        if not b[0].startswith(prefixes):
            print([a[0] + "  " + b[0]])
        else:
            print([a[0]])
    a = b
print([a[0]])
```

with output

```
['JAVS P 0 060107084657.30  59.41 0 S']
[' CEY P 0 060107084659.39  03.10 0 S']
['CADS P 0 060107084703.67']
['VISS P 0 060107084704.14']
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the case... I edited original post, because my output is not list of list, as it was before, but just a list. There was a duplicated list in the original script.

Comment: Actualy it works, thanks, I just had to remove [] from a and b!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pairwise` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to itertate through your data in pairs.

```
import itertools

mydata = [
    [u'JAVS P 0 060107084657.30'],
    ['59.41 0 S'],
    [u' CEY P 0 060107084659.39'],
    ['03.10 0 S'],
    [u'CADS P 0 060107084703.67'],
    [u'VISS P 0 060107084704.14'],
]


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

prefixes = ('JAVS', ' CEY', 'CADS', 'VISS')

for a, b in pairwise(mydata):
    if a[0].startswith(prefixes):
        if not b[0].startswith(prefixes):
            print a + b
        else:
            print a
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not get any output... I edited original post to include my full script with your part.